# How to count the number of columns in a pyspark RDD?

Tags: python, pyspark, rdd

How to count the number of columns in a pyspark RDD without converting it to a Dataframe?

Why they don't have a build-in function to count columns? For rows, there are *.count()*.

Comment: Probably because RDD are not columns oriented object but Key/values ...

Comment: but the teacher asked us to do so

Comment: Start with the definition of column. What about complex types ? Are elements withing a dict considered as columns too ? But surely, if your teacher asked it, that must be possible ... 

Answer (score -1):

One way is

```
len(rdd.take(1)[0])
```